# How to make curved line for 2 points in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

Is possible to draw a curve line between 2 near points in leaflet, for example with these coordinates:

```
point_1 = (23.634501, -102.552783)

point_2 = (17.987557, -92.929147)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to find an [online tutorial](https://medium.com/@ryancatalani/creating-consistently-curved-lines-on-leaflet-b59bc03fa9dc) that shows how to make curved lines between points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Wrokar implied this can be achieved using [Leaflet.curve](https://github.com/elfalem/Leaflet.curve) library. You can simply use the code provided by this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ryancatalani/6091e50bf756088bf9bf5de2017b32e6) and replace your coordinates with the ones defined in variable latlng1 & latlng2 respectively.

```
var latlng1 = [LATITUDE, LONGTITUDE],
    latlng2 = [LATITUDE, LONGTITUDE];
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -10], 1);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var latlngs = [];

var latlng1 = [23.634501, -102.552783],
  latlng2 = [17.987557, -92.929147];

var offsetX = latlng2[1] - latlng1[1],
  offsetY = latlng2[0] - latlng1[0];

var r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(offsetX, 2) + Math.pow(offsetY, 2)),
  theta = Math.atan2(offsetY, offsetX);

var thetaOffset = (3.14 / 10);

var r2 = (r / 2) / (Math.cos(thetaOffset)),
  theta2 = theta + thetaOffset;

var midpointX = (r2 * Math.cos(theta2)) + latlng1[1],
  midpointY = (r2 * Math.sin(theta2)) + latlng1[0];

var midpointLatLng = [midpointY, midpointX];

latlngs.push(latlng1, midpointLatLng, latlng2);

var pathOptions = {
  color: 'red',
  weight: 3
}

var curvedPath = L.curve(
  [
    'M', latlng1,
    'Q', midpointLatLng,
    latlng2
  ], pathOptions).addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#mapid {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<script src="https://elfalem.github.io/Leaflet.curve/src/leaflet.curve.js"></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer! Do you know how to add a marker to the middle of the curve? I can't seem to get the coordinates right.